# Euclidean motion and illustration matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be linear. When $\Phi$ is an Euclidean motion, than is \begin{pmatrix} c&-s\\s&c\\  \end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix} c&s\\s&-c\\ \end{pmatrix} the illustration matrix of $\Phi$ with $c,s\;\mathbb{\in}\;\mathbb{R}$ and $c^2+s^2=1$.

When $\Phi$ is an Euclidean motion, than $||\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)||=||x-y||$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want help with? If it’s proving the last identity, that’s a straightforward algebraic manipulation of the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is it that you ara calling an Euclidean movement, but your first matrix is the matrix, with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^2$, of a rotation around the origin, whereas the second one is the matrix of a reflection on a line through the origin.

Comment: I hope Euclidean motion is the right word